# How to detect input value lanaguage

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, field

So I have a input field: `<input type="text" id="input">`
When users are pressing on keyboard and are typing something inside this field I want to detect input value lanaguage using Javascript. I need your help to done this small task...

Comment: That is not a **small task**...You need a database to save all the languages, sometimes users might use their custom words there, like 'yo! hw r u, m fyn u tl'. What would you do then?

Comment: I think you're underestimating this, detecting the language of a string is not a small task. Your best bet will be to find an API offering such functionality.

Comment: Use https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started#language_detect

Comment: What do you mean by detect input value language ? Hope not what I'm thinking about ...

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter: Exactly what we need for a current project. Cheers!

Comment: What language is the word "non"? English? French? Spanish? Italian? Afrikaans? Basque? Bosnian? Haitian Creole? Dutch? Latin? Malay?